# when i put the parameters in JCheckBox it gives error

Tags: java, jcheckbox

when i put the parameters inside the JCheckBox it gives error.

public class JCheckBox extends JTextField{

```
JCheckBox(){
 JFrame f= new JFrame("CheckBox Example");  
    JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("c++");  
    checkBox1.setBounds(100,100, 50,50);  
    JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox();  
    checkBox2.setBounds(100,150, 50,50);  
    f.add(checkBox1);  
    f.add(checkBox2);  
    f.setSize(400,400);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new JCheckBox(); 
}
```

}

Comment: And the error is? Do we have to guess it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which error?

Comment: You might want to avoid naming your class [JCheckBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html) as it is part of Swing.

Comment: After looking at your code... Creating objects recursively inside of the object's constructor is a terrible idea. I mean calling `new JCheckBox()` inside of a `JCheckBox` constructor.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Thank you. I changed the class name and it worked.

Comment: The `StackOverflowError` would have help you understand that `JCheckBox` constructor was calling itself.